# SQL query to count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently practicing PHP and MySQL just to strengthen my skills, as i am new to programming and i am trying different things out :)

I have made a basic website where users can enter a word and the database will save it, just for fun. But instead of storing the same word repeatedly i want SQL to be able to allow me to see that apple has been stored 3 times, rather than [apple,apple,apple] in my column.

**How can I get SQL to do this?** I have only seen the count() function online so i am a little confused.

Comment: Thank you i will have a read now :)

Answer (score 8):

You can either:

- simply select the count of each word after insertion:

  ```sql
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE word = 'apple'
  ```
- maintain the count in the table:

  1. Add a `count` column, together with a `UNIQUE` index on your word column:

     ```sql
     ALTER TABLE my_table
       ADD count INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1,
       ADD UNIQUE INDEX (word)
     ```
  2. Instead of using `INSERT`, use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

     ```sql
     INSERT INTO my_table
       (word)
     VALUES
       ('apple')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       count = count + 1
     ```
  3. Fetch the count from the table:

     ```sql
     SELECT count FROM my_table WHERE word = 'apple'
     ```

Comment: it's nice but please mind mind about `grave accent` chars as `count` is reserved word

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: `COUNT` is *not* a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  Indeed: "*Names of built-in functions are permitted as identifiers but may require care to be used as such. For example, `COUNT` is acceptable as a column name.*"

Comment: Thanks so much! Is the (word) specifying that it will be a word? or do i need to enter the word to index?

Comment: @AdamJones: No, that is the (assumed) name of your column.

Comment: @eggyal ehh you know what i mean, it's always better to use quotation   `Names of built-in functions are permitted as identifiers but may require care to be used as such. `

Comment: @eggyal i mean, please use quotation

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: If you like, but it isn't necessary!

Comment: My solution was the same, I was just too slow again, but this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25339/1) might be useful to further illustrate this answer.

Comment: @eggyal this could be too , `Select count(word='apple') from yourtable;` ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo: That won't work... that will give the number of non-NULL `word` records in the whole table.  Perhaps you meant to use `SUM`?  But even then, it's not especially efficient as it won't resolve using indexes (if available).